# TypeError: argument od type 'int' is not iterable on File "<string>", line 31, in <module>

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import math
import random

options = ("Snorkeling","Scuba Diving","Fishing","Sunbathing","Shopping","Helicopter Ride","Sleeping")
prices  = (10.00, 150.00, 25.00, 0.00, 200.00, 450.00, 0.00)
startDateString = input("Enter the starting date of your vacation (MM/DD/YYYY): ")
startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startDateString, '%m/%d/%Y')
stopDateString = input("Enter the ending date of your vacation (MM/DD/YYYY): ")
stopDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(stopDateString, '%m/%d/%Y')
Delta = (stopDate - startDate)

print("Your vacation is", Delta.days, "days long")

costs = []

for i in range(1, 7, Delta.days):
    ActivityIndex = random.randrange(len(options))
    activity = options in ActivityIndex
    cost = prices in ActivityIndex
    thisDate = (startDate + datetime.timedelta (days=i))
    thisDateString = datetime.datetime.strftime(thisDate, '%m/%d/%y')

    print(str.format("On {}, {} costs ${:.2f}",thisDateString,activity,cost))

    costs.append(cost)
    print(str.format("The most expensive day cost ${}", max(costs)))
    print(str.format("The least expensive day cost ${}", min(costs)))
```

Comment: `ActivityIndex` is an int. What is `options in ActivityIndex` supposed to mean?

Comment: Please cut and paste the whole, exact error message you got.

Comment: Please include the raised in the descript as well as a small introduction of what you trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

As confusing as it sounds, [`random.randrange` returns an integer](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.randrange), not a "random range", as one might think, so in this code:

```
ActivityIndex = random.randrange(len(options))
activity = options in ActivityIndex
cost = prices in ActivityIndex
```

...`ActivityIndex` is an integer, and `options in ActivityIndex` will attempt to iterate over this single integer, which is impossible.

Comment: How could i fix this issue?

Comment: @RichardTruong, maybe you meant `activity = random.choice(options)` and `cost = random.choice(prices)`?

Comment: @RichardTruong, you put `print(str.format("The most expensive day cost ${}", max(costs)))` _inside the loop_, so it'll print the current max and min on each iteration

Comment: @RichardTruong, in this case, `activity = options[ActivityIndex]` and `cost = prices[ActivityIndex]`

Comment: Thank you that worked, but how can I make the print(str.format("The most expensive day cost ${}", max(costs))) print once?

Comment: As I explained in the other comment, this code is _in a loop_, so it'll be executed _on each iteration_. How to make it execute once (presumably after the loop) - move it outside the loop

Comment: Oh, I did not realize. Thank you for your explanation I have fixed the coding issue.